# Dependency Injection in extended classes

Tags: php, dependency-injection

How best to handle dependency intejection with extended classes. eg: filterIterator.

```
<?php
class myIterator extends filterIterator{
  public function __construct( directoryIterator $iterator ){
    parent::__construct( $iterator );
  }
}

$it = new myIterator( new directoryIterator( $path ) );
?>
```

Comment: in your example, there is no need to declare a constructor because it will inherit from parent and achieve the same thing. you'll need to call `parent` only if you want to add dependencies.

Comment: Not sure how that would work.. If a filterIterator takes a directoryIterator as an arg to the constructor. How could dependency injection work when the directoryIterator would need to have a value?